# Where to store Profile Picture of Users?

Tags: 2007, user-profile, my-profile

Can any body please guide me where should I store the profile Image of the user? The problem is that SharePoint expects a url in Picture field of Profile.

I was looking for some solution where every user can upload/change his/her own photo whenever needed, just like facebook without thinking of storage location.

What is the best practice to store profile images of every user? Should I create a separate library called "Profile Pictures" and upload all images? It will be too cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Social team blog has an article about photo within the MySite.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spsocial/photo-management-in-sharepoint-2010)

This should shed some more light.

Answer (score 0):

If they are using MySites, they can upload pictures to their own picture library and set them as their profile pictures. However, if you do not allow mysites, you can create a site with permissions that are appropriate for this, upload their pictures there, and then use something like SUSHI to set the URLs for them in their Profiles. Once you have done that, you can tell the users the naming convention that they need to use for their pictures (usually username.jpg) and then let them upload new pictures overwriting the old pictures as needed. However, you will have to set the URL initially or they will for all new user profiles.

Comment: Thanks Lori, but user experience is not good when you ask your users to first upload a picture somewhere (mysite or some other library), copy the url and paste it in Picture property. 
Normally, users just want to change their picture in a facebook way i.e. click upload and thats it, without ever being concerned about the location.